# which one is recommended object-oriented design?

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented, object-oriented-design

I made simple object-oriented prgram, and think about design.
I wonder which one of belows is recommended object-oriented design.

Most left side class is "Main" class. Black arrow means they are "Has a" relations. Blue arrows are inheritance. Red arrows mean it create pointed class as a object and call the method of it. Thanks.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Based on the available information, the second of these options is the best choice.  But without knowing the domain, none of this makes any sense.

Comment: It's very likely that you don't need all of those inheritance relationships.  You may not need any of them.  It kinda depends on your problem domain and what the classes are doing.

Comment: It looks like the only difference is the red arrow part. If the black arrows ("has a" relation) are in inherited structure as the graph shows, the second one seems make more sense for a simple object oriented program. But actually you need to think about the dependency of class and the workflow of the system to decide whether a class should be created (or inited) by its owner / container, by global factory class, or at the start point of your program.

Answer (score 3):

> "Red arrows mean it create pointed class as a object and call the method of it."

So you did not separate creation from usage?

This is pretty much opinionated, but one "recommended" way of creating OO programs, especially when multiple classes are involved, is to make use of [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). One central aspect of DI is: if one object needs another object, it does not create it directly, but it gets the object "injected" from outside (the rationale behind is that it will allow you to write unit tests by injecting mocks instead of the "real" objects).

So if you implement DI "manually", without a "generic DI container component", and without any additional factory classes, this means, outside of your test code, there must be a central place, often just the "main" program, where all the objects are created and "assembled together". This leads straight forward to a **creation** graph which looks like your first picture.

Nevertheless the gist of object orientation is that you have a **usage** graph like the second one - objects which are related communicate directly to each other through some defined interfaces, and you try to keep dependencies as local as possible. The intention behind this is to keep the impact of later changes low.

For small programs the effort of introducing DI may not be worth the hassle, so following another "recommended way" - the [YAGNI principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it) - might be the better way to go, and having a creation graph like the second one can be fine, even for a lot of real world scenarios. Moreover, real world scenarios will typically use a mixed approach. For example, if some of your classes represent pure data objects, without any business logic, there is no much benefit to "mock them out", so creating those objects directly where they are needed may be perfectly ok, whilst for other classes you may choose to apply DI.

Comment: +1 for the essential hints of creation vs. usage and the trade-offs involved in following OO principles.

Answer (score 2):

This is issue of following the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter). In first case, the Main class knows about all the other classes. If it has dependency on all of those classes, then you have to check if Main works properly if you change any of those classes + the one that is using it. If you needed to mock dependencies of Main class, then you would have to mock all of those dependencies.

In the second case, that is not a problem, assuming those dependencies are encapsulated and not accessible transitively. Each of the classes has only one dependency, making them easier to test and reason about.

If you can access all of the classes transitively (eg. `Main.A.B.C`), then there is not much difference between first and second case and I would really question your whole design.